# Rust parsing error handling issue when running in main

Tags: exception, rust

I am new to Rust, so forgive me if I ask a stupid question.

I made a custom error handler like this:

```
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    #[error("Entered number cannot be parsed")]
    ParseError,
}
```

And I want to set it in main, so when the error happens - I get my custom error. What is the best way to do so?

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {
          //read number from the console

         let specific_number = match number.parse() {
                Ok(number) => number,
                 _=> return Err(Error::ParseError)
            };
}
```

this returns Error::ParseError and I want to get the error message Entered number cannot be parsed in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return an error in `main`, it uses the `Debug` formatter. I couldn't find this documented anywhere, but the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/process.rs.html#2210-2220) is pretty understandable:

```rs
impl<T: Termination, E: fmt::Debug> Termination for Result<T, E> {
    fn report(self) -> ExitCode {
        match self {
            Ok(val) => val.report(),
            Err(err) => {
                io::attempt_print_to_stderr(format_args_nl!("Error: {err:?}"));
                ExitCode::FAILURE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`io::attempt_print_to_stderr(format_args_nl!("Error: {err:?}"))` is essentially `eprintln!("Error: {err:?}")`.

There's a few things you can do to use the `Display` impl instead, which is what `thiserror` puts the error message in.

## Wrap `main`

Put your entire `main` function into another function, call that in main, and print the error manually: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b38fe6837068c57d668b849af0ebbbd)

```rs
fn main_() -> Result<()> {
    //read number from the console
    let number = "5.0";

    let _specific_number: i32 = match number.parse() {
        Ok(number) => number,
        _ => return Err(Error::ParseError),
    };

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = main_() {
        eprintln!("{e}");
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

## Make your own return type

You can implement `Termination` for your own type, and return that from `main` instead of `Result`: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68aa23d1a1c53d93d5205580f8ebe5d5)

```rs
struct DisplayResult<T>(Result<T>);

impl<T> Termination for DisplayResult<T> where T: Termination {
    fn report(self) -> ExitCode {
        match self.0 {
            Ok(t) => t.report(),
            Err(e) => {
                // Use the `Display` impl
                eprintln!("{e}");
                ExitCode::FAILURE
            },
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<Result<T>> for DisplayResult<T> {
    fn from(r: Result<T>) -> Self {
        DisplayResult(r)
    }
}

fn main() -> DisplayResult<()> {
    //read number from the console
    let number = "5.0";

    let _specific_number: i32 = match number.parse() {
        Ok(number) => number,
        _ => return Err(Error::ParseError).into(),
    };

    Ok(()).into()
}
```

The unfortunate side of this is since `FromResidual` is unstable, you can't use `?` (try operator) to create `DisplayResult` on stable. And when it does become stable, you need yet another impl block (plus another if you want to use `?` on it directly) for this simple type: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fbbc8d3b6b75c643fb374d0caa5ace32)

```rs
impl FromResidual<Result<Infallible>> for DisplayResult<()> {
    fn from_residual(residual: Result<Infallible>) -> Self {
        Self(residual.map(|_| ()))
    }
}
```

## Change `Debug`

Technically, you could leave `main` the same, and implement `Debug` on `Error` manually to use `Error`'s `Display` impl. However, this goes against what `Debug` is for, and I wouldn't use this for any case.

## Conclusion

Because of the current drawbacks in implementing `Termination`, I would recommend using the first method and wrapping `main`.